# Tag friends in photo upload facebook api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

How can i tag friends in my upload?

I have tried this, but doesn't seem to work properly.

```
 var tags = "{'tag_uid' : 10000,'x' : 100,'y': 100}";

 FB.api('me/photos', 'post', {
                    message: 'MyMessage',
                    status: 'success',
                    url: 'picture.png',
                    tags: tags
                }, function (response) {
                    if (!response || response.error) {
                       alert("Could not upload. " + response.error);
                    } else {
                        alert("Yihad!");
                    }
   })
```

Comment: Do you have the `user_photos` and `publish_stream` permissions?

Comment: yes i have already done that.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter tags must be an array, make tags an array, put more values in tags:

var tags = [{"tag_uid" : "abcdef" , "x" : "100" ,"y" : "100"},{"tag_uid" : "uvwxyz" , "x" : "100" ,"y" : "100"}];